# Cannot generate new puppet certificates with new puppet master

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet

Created a new Puppet Master to upgrade to Puppet6

Did "rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl" to clear old certificates

After pointing the old client at the new master, the client cannot generate new certificates.

Error received is this:

```
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN={server FQDN}]
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN={server FQDN}]
```

How do I get the Client to generate a new certificate?

Answer (score 3):

Please delete the ssl folder on the puppet client too and try again a puppet agent --waitforcert 60 --test

Answer (score 0):

A new certificate has to be generated on the client end so that it can be signed by the new puppetmaster, hence the existing certificates have to be deleted on the client side:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl
```

On the server-side

```sh
puppetserver ca clean --certname <hostname_of_client>
rm -rf /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
```